# Opeansea does not preview gltf animations of gltf files stored in ipfs

Tags: nft, opensea, meta-data

In theory opeansea supports gltf and gtb files using the [animation_url](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards) in json file. However they don't render the animation and just display the text of the the gltf file and does not render it (see screenshot) [image: opensea render of the gltf].

I uploaded the gltf file and in the json of the metadata I have

```json
{
   ...
   animation_url: "ipfs://<CID>"
   ...
}
```

It does display the preview image correctly.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days experimentation I found that opensea only renders the gltf file if the metadata has has filename and fileextension `file.ext` at the end and is not only a ipfs link.

correct metadata format:

```json
{
   ...
   animation_url: "ipfs://<CID>/filename.gltf"
   ...
}
```

Apparently with images this is not a problem, you can use images with the format `image: "ipfs://<CID>"` but not with the `animation_url` tag.